# Taylor series in little or big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is  $m$ times continuously differentiable  Consider a point $a\in \mathbb{R}$ around which we will Taylor expand and define $h=b-a$. Then:
$$f(b) = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} h^k + o(h^m)$$

This means the remainder $ R_m(h) = f(b) - \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} h^k$ converges faster to $0$ then $h^m$ for $h \rightarrow 0$

If we now assume that $f$ is $m+1$ times continuously differentiable, then we can rewrite the taylor series in Big O notation:

$$f(b) = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} h^k + O(h^{m+1})$$

Why do we need this extra differentiability here. We do not use the $f^{(m+1)}$?

Furthermore the Big O notations implies, that the remainder $\frac{R(h)}{h^{m+1}}$ converges to a constant and not $0$ zero as in the case before.

So we end up with different behaviour of the remainder. What am I missing here?

Comment: There are explicit integral formulas for the remainders in each case (do the case $m = 0, 1$ if you don't want to look up the formulas). From those it is evident why the result holds.

Comment: The existence and continuity at $a$ of $f^{(m+1)}$ produces a finer result $O(h^{m+1})$. The big $O$ notation does not imply that $\frac{R(h)}{h^{m+1}}$ converges to a constant, but that it is bounded (for $h$ in some fixed neighborhood of $0$). This implies $\frac{R(h)}{h^m}\to0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval: The continuity of  $f^{(m+1)}$ implies that f is bounded on a closed interval isn't it?

Comment: @AnneBauval: How do you conclude that $\frac{R(h)}{h^{m}}$ goes to 0 in that case?

Comment: 1) Yes but the continuity *at $a$* (which implies boundedness in some neighborhood of $a$) is sufficient for our purposes. 2) $\frac{R(h)}{h^{m}}=\frac{R(h)}{h^{m+1}}\, h.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. But when remainder is bounded in the second case, we do not know if it converges to $0$? $R(h)= O(h^{m+1})  \Rightarrow |R(h)| \leq c |h|^{m+1}$ for $h$ around $0$.

Comment: Or we can we simply let $h \rightarrow 0$ to obtain  $|R(h)| \leq 0$

Comment: Neither $|R(h)|\le0$ (?), nor $|R(h)|\to0$ but much better: $R(h)=o(h^m)$, since $|R(h)/h^m|\le c|h|$ (as indicated in my last comment, 2 hours ago).

Comment: But should the remainder not converge to 0?

Comment: In the second case the remainder the remainder is bounded by $c|h|^{m+1}$ for small $h$. So we can let h go to $0$. Then the remainder would be zero and the taylor polynomial a good approximation at a ?

Comment: What do you mean that the big O notation produces a finer result?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't say that the two results indicate strictly different behavior. The first result has a weaker hypothesis and also a weaker conclusion (which is essentially the definition of "$m$ times differentiable); the second result has a stronger hypothesis and also a stronger conclusion, but the weaker conclusion is still true of course.

The proofs I know of the second result go through more exact results that explicitly invoke the $(m+1)$st derivative—see [Theorem 3.6.11 in this online textbook](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP2/clp_2_ic/subsubsection-17.html) for example.

Now it's conceivable that the result as stated (which doesn't overtly reference $f^{(m+1)}$ as you point out) could have some other proof that never uses $f^{(m+1)}$, but I think that turns out not to be the case. Consider the specific function $f(x) = x^{m+1/3}$ at $a=0$ for example: the function is $m$ times differentiable, but the second conclusion fails for this function.